# PHPUnit test results - Unexpected HTML output

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpunit

I am using wamp + phpunit + Codeigniter for unit testing. When I execute the phpunit on the test folder there are some html codes from the index.php is also printing on the CLI as on the image.

PHPUnit version is 4.1

How to fix this? or avoid this html codes from the output?
[image]

Comment: can't find a solution. perhaps rewrite your tests for finer components?

Comment: same test is working good in the MAC OS, this is showing only in windows, any clue?

Comment: looks like output is [automatically suppressed](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/411) for phpunit version 3.6+, your windows one might be lower

Comment: Don't test view with phpunit, use e2e tests to do that... I use to write a test bootstrap file, which has autoload, but does not try to dispatch any request, since we don't have one...

Answer (score 1):

You test is producing an error (Failures: 1). The error is that the output does not match the PCRE pattern /Your are done!/.